# MAPQUEST API "optimizedroute" vs optimizeWaypoints: true

Tags: mapquest

I would like to know is using optimizedroute
[http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/optimizedroute?key=KEY&json={"locations":["Denver,CO","Westminster,CO","Boulder,CO"]}](http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/optimizedroute?key=KEY&json=%7B%22locations%22:%5B%22Denver,CO%22,%22Westminster,CO%22,%22Boulder,CO%22%5D%7D)

vs Route using waypoints and setting optimizeWaypoints: true

Will these two produce the same route?

Thanks,
Joy

Answer (score 0):

The MapQuest request is correct to get locations between the origin and destination rearranged for the best route.

I'm not a Google expert but that does seem to be the correct way to get a similar function from their API.